# Python: straight line, Slope k is known, one point P1 is known, length P1P2 is known, how to get P2?

Tags: python

For a straight line, Slope k is known, one point(x1,y1) is know, how to get the other point (x2,y2) using python?
I know the way to do calculation, but have no idea to code using python.

1. (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)=k
2. sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2)= length

if two unknown equations, both two variables with power 1, linalg-solve should work, but now the power of 2rd function is 2, how to deal with that?

I tried to simplify as following, but seems I cannot apply linalg-solve

1. kx2-y2-kx1+y1 = 0
2. (y2-y1)^2 + (x2-x1)^2 = length^2

**Supplement：**
thanks to all of your answer...Posh_Pumpkin's code is exactly what I want, previously I thought I need to apply linalg-solve which I usually use.

here is a test code based on his answer:suppose P1 = (1,1) p2=(x,y), p1p2= sqrt(2), k=1,then p2 must be = (2,2)

```
import numpy as np
import math
k = 1
d = math.sqrt(2)
p1 = (1,1)
r_sq = d**2 / (1 + k**2)
r = math.sqrt(r_sq)
p2 = (p1[0] + r, p1[1] + k*r)
print(p2)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question? What part of the calculation is difficult for you to code? How much do you already know about Python?

Comment: For a straight line, there are going to be two points a given distance D from your point (x1, y1). One at (x1+dx, y1+dy) and the other at (x1-dx, y1-dy). You should look for information about the *arc tangent* function (called `atan`) to convert a slope to an angle. From there, sine and cosine will give you dx and dy.

Comment: Your question is not really about Python, but about trigonometry. Once you have a trig formula to solve your problem, it can be easily coded into Python.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far (forming a [mcve]), example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: yes, thanks, I will pay more attention to make the question more specific next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use a complicated solution at all? I would approach it under the assumption that `P1 = (0, 0)`.

Assuming `P1` is at the origin, and knowing that the `slope = k`, you know that `P2 = (r, k*r)` for a constant `r`. The `r` can be computed by calculating the distance `P1P2`. Since you said you already know the distance, we can then simply do:

```
r^2 + (k*r)^2 = d^2
```

To find `r`. Once you find `r`, you can get the coordinates of `P2` when `P1 = (0, 0)`. So to find the actual coordinates, you'd just do `P2 = P1 + P2`. Check below:

```
import math

# Obviously assume k and d are known constants, and P1 is a known point
k = # given k
d = # given d
p1 = # (given x coord, given y coord)

r_sq = d**2 / (1 + k**2)
r = math.sqrt(r_sq)
p2 = (p1[0] + r, p1[1] + k*r)
print(p2)
```

If you have to use `numpy`, you should show us your code and what exactly is troubling you. What is preventing you from using the module, whether it's an error or an unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with basic trig.  Here is the general derivation.

```
let p1 = (x1,y1) & p2 = (x2 = x1+d, y2 = y1+h), 
let L be the distance between p1 & p2 
* note for p1 & p2 such that x1 != x2 && y1 != y2, a triangle can be formed Ldh such that tan(theta) = h/d

h/d is the slope of the line (m) connecting points p1 & p2, so tan(theta) = m
 => theta = atan(m), from the law of sines ( sin(a)/A = sin(b)/B ) 
 => sin(90)/L = sin(atan(theta))/y2
 => y2 = L*sin( atan(theta) )

now get x from the point slope form of a line y= y1+m(x-x1) = (y-y1)/m +x1
so x2 = (y2-y1)/m + x1
```

Here is this expressed in python:

```
from math import sin,  atan
from random import randint

# This is the formula for (x2,y2) = p2
x = lambda y2, m, x1, y1: (y2 - y1)/float(m) + x1
y = lambda l, m, y1: l*sin( atan(m)  ) + y1

# p2 constraints ( x2 > x1, y2 > y1 or x2 > x1, y2 < y1 )
p1 =  [randint(1,1000),randint(1,1000)]
p2 =  [randint(p1[0],1001),randint(0,p1[1])]

# calculate distance between p1 & p2 (L), also calculate slope (m)
slope = lambda x1,y1,x2,y2: (y2-y1)/float(x2-x1)
dist  = lambda x1,y1,x2,y2: ( (y2-y1)**2 + (x2-x1)**2  )**(0.5)
L = dist(p1[0],p1[1],p2[0],p2[1])
m = slope(p1[0],p1[1],p2[0],p2[1])

#  now see if our functions for x & y yield p2
y2 = y(L,m,p1[1])
p_derived = [ x(y2,m,p1[0],p1[1]),y2  ]
print "p1: ",p1 , "p2 actual: ",p2, "p2 derived: ",p_derived
```

So here I generate two random points p1 and p2, and verify that p2 can be calculated from the slope, distance, and p1 by comparing my derived result to the actual result.

Comment: yes, thank you very much for the answer, that is it.